# CS50: fatal errors in credit.c

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I am a really new programmer, written 3 codes before! (Hello World included!)
I really tried to figure out an algorithm that could help me figure out the credit.c program, but my program keeps on running errors. the code is quite messy right now, but I will try and design t better if I get to know it is functional first. This is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void);
long long CCno;//since int cant hold this long number
{  
    do
    {
      x = get_long_long("Number: ") //asks for user to input cc number
    }
    while (x < 0 || x > 9999999999999999); //returns a non zero number
}


int numcount = 0;
int numcount = (x == 0) ? 1 : (log(x) + 1);
//calculate checksum

//Finds alternate numbers and multiplies with 2
        int digit1 = (((x % 100) / 10) * 2);
        int digit2 = (((x % 10000) / 1000) * 2);
        int digit3 = (((x % 1000000) / 100000) * 2);
        int digit4 = (((x % 100000000) / 10000000) * 2);
        int digit5 = (((x % 10000000000) / 1000000000) * 2);
        int digit6 = (((x % 1000000000000) / 100000000000) * 2);
        int digit7 = (((x % 100000000000000) / 10000000000000) * 2);
        int digit8 = (((x % 10000000000000000) / 1000000000000000) * 2);

//Find the other remaining numbers
        int digit9 = ((x % 10) / 1);
        int digit10 = ((x % 100) / 10);
        int digit11 = ((x % 1000) / 100);
        int digit12 = ((x % 10000) / 1000);
        int digit13 = ((x % 100000) / 10000); 
        int digit14 = ((x % 1000000) / 100000);
        int digit15 = ((x % 10000000) / 1000000);
        int digit16 = ((x % 100000000) / 10000000);

        int sum1 = ((digit1 % 10) + (digit1 / 10));
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit2 % 10)) + (digit2 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit3 % 10)) + (digit3 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit4 % 10)) + (digit4 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit5 % 10)) + (digit5 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit6 % 10)) + (digit6 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit7 % 10)) + (digit7 / 10);
        sum1 = (sum1 + (digit8 % 10)) + (digit8 / 10);

int checksum = (sum1 + digit9 + digit10 + digit11 + digit12 + digit13 + digit14 + digit15 + digit16)

//check first two digits

    if
    {
        (numcount == 15)
        (digit1 == 3 && digit2 == 4 || 7)
        printf("AMEX");
    }

    if
    {
        (numcount == 13 || 16)
        (digit1 == 4)
        printf("VISA");
    }
    if
    {
        (numcount == 16)
        (digit1 == 5 && digit2 == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)
        printf("MASTERCARD");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
```

please help me figure out the errors!!
edit- All the other errors have now been corrected, there is still one yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( void ); 

long long x;//since int cant hold this long number
{
    do
    {
      x = get_long_long("Number: ") //asks for user to input cc number
    }
    while (x < 0 || x > 9999999999999999); //returns a non zero number



   int numcount = 0;
   int numcount = (x == 0) ? 1 : (log(x) + 1);
    //calculate checksum

    //Finds alternate numbers and multiplies with 2
        int digit1 = (((x % 100) / 10) * 2);
        int digit2 = (((x % 10000) / 1000) * 2);
        int digit3 = (((x % 1000000) / 100000) * 2);
        int digit4 = (((x % 100000000) / 10000000) * 2);
        int digit5 = (((x % 10000000000) / 1000000000) * 2);
        int digit6 = (((x % 1000000000000) / 100000000000) * 2);
        int digit7 = (((x % 100000000000000) / 10000000000000) * 2);
        int digit8 = (((x % 10000000000000000) / 1000000000000000) * 2);

//Find the other remaining numbers
        int digit9 = ((x % 10) / 1);
        int digit10 = ((x % 100) / 10);
        int digit11 = ((x % 1000) / 100);
        int digit12 = ((x % 10000) / 1000);
        int digit13 = ((x % 100000) / 10000); 
        int digit14 = ((x % 1000000) / 100000);
        int digit15 = ((x % 10000000) / 1000000);
        int digit16 = ((x % 100000000) / 10000000);

        int sum1 = ((digit1 % 10) + (digit1 / 10));
        sum2 = (sum1 + (digit2 % 10)) + (digit2 / 10);
        sum3 = (sum1 + (digit3 % 10)) + (digit3 / 10);
        sum4 = (sum1 + (digit4 % 10)) + (digit4 / 10);
        sum5 = (sum1 + (digit5 % 10)) + (digit5 / 10);
        sum6 = (sum1 + (digit6 % 10)) + (digit6 / 10);
        sum7 = (sum1 + (digit7 % 10)) + (digit7 / 10);
        sum8 = (sum1 + (digit8 % 10)) + (digit8 / 10);

int checksum = (sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5 + sum6 + sum7 + sum8 + digit9 + digit10 + digit11 + digit12 + digit13 + digit14 + digit15 + digit16)

//check first two digits

    if
    {
        (numcount == 15)
        (digit1 == 3 && digit2 == 4 || 7)
        printf("AMEX");
    }

    if
    {
        (numcount == 13 || 16)
        (digit1 == 4)
        printf("VISA");
    }
    if
    {
        (numcount == 16)
        (digit1 == 5 && digit2 == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)
        printf("MASTERCARD");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
}
```

this is the error message-

```
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow 
   credit.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o credit
credit.c:8:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'credit' failed
make: *** [credit] Error 1
```

Comment: What errors are you experiencing?  Logical or syntactical?

Comment: The series of `sum1 = (sum1 + (digit2 % 10)) + (digit2 / 10);` etc. is undoubtedly incorrect.  You probably want `+=` instead of `=` or `sum2`, `sum3`, etc.

Comment: Syntactical errors as of now, i am yet to figure out the logical part yet. Got rid of all but one right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
int main(void); // <-- get rid of this semicolon
long long CCno; // <-- this either needs to be declared above main, or between
{               //     the {} of the function body
    do
    {
      x = get_long_long("Number: ") //asks for user to input cc number
    }
    while (x < 0 || x > 9999999999999999); //returns a non zero number
}
```

As a first step, rewrite as follows:

```
int main( void )
{
  long long CCNo;

  // do loop as written above

  // everything involving numcount, digit, etc.
}
```

There are still plenty of issues, but that should get you past a couple of your errors at least.

Comment: Maybe `int main(void);` is a forward declaration?  It's hard to tell what OPs intent is.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Based on what's been posted, I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Note also that the closing brace of `main`, the `}`, should be at the end of all his code.